# Secure keyboard entry with JavaScript or Flash?

Tags: web-browser, javascript, flash

Is it possible to perform secure keyboard entry (similar to what is offered in the OS X Terminal app) using only web technologies and/or Flash?

If not, is there any way to more broadly guarantee exclusive/isolated access to input devices, or to check whether or not a device has been read or manipulated by external processes since start of observation?

I assume this is impossible with JavaScript alone, however I am not familiar with Flash and have heard of more extensive capabilities being offered (usually hear about them being abused) than JS would permit.

Comment: I suppose this probably would not be available since the abstraction would be more troublesome to maintain across platforms than would be justified by the few benefits it would yield.

Answer (score 2):

No, since that would imply that Flash or JavaScript does have access to raw hardware, outside of its sandbox.

Think opposite, that if a flash applet or JavaScript applet would have this access, it would be possible to build a keylogging website that remained Active across tabs.

If you need to protect against keyloggers, I would suggest some sort of 2FA. Then it wont matter if the password does fall in the wrong hands, as long as the token does not fall in the wrong hands.